# Transfer SQL Server data to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ssms

I have a local database SQL Server 2008 Express and I have tables along with data in them. I want to export those schemas and data to SQL Azure database.

What I have tried in SQL Management Studio is to right-click database (contextual menu) and Tasks->Generate Scripts. But those SQL scripts were only the schema, stored procedures etc and no data is exported at all.

Then I have tried Tasks->Export Data, but there were no appropriate export types. I have seen only Flat File dump and I think SQL Mgmt Studio 2008 R2 does not support importing flat files for SQL Azure.

Is there a nicer way to export data from SQL Server as sql scripts and execute them on a remote server without using any 3rd party tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that SQL Azure Migration Tool http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

Very handy and useful. Worked for me.

Comment: I had to comment out `Microsoft.ExceptionMessageBox` in `Dependencies.xml` to get it to run.. after that everything was smooth!

Comment: Does that work using command line or does it need User Input ?

Comment: broken link, please amend

Comment: project appears to be dead. feel free to click Edit on my comment.

Answer (score 2):

In Tasks/Generate Scripts you can set Script Options/Script Data to be True, which should script out the data as well.

Not free, but [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) will let you move data from on-premise to SQL Azure.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **SQL Server Import and Export Wizard**.

For Detailed steps reg how to do it, check [link](https://arulmouzhi.wordpress.com/2020/02/11/to-copy-and-sync-database-tables-across-different-server/).

I have worked with it already and it **works fine for both Azure and on-premises**.

Answer (score -3):

An article that comprehensively explains available options:

http://parasdoshi.com/2011/06/20/solidq-journal-article-migrating-data-into-microsofts-data-platform-sql-azure/

Full disclosure: i work at SolidQ.com

Comment: This link goes to a page with broken link to the article in question.